# Remote File Download Script of php not works on server but works my xampp

Tags: php, linux, remote-access

Its been couple of hours, tried all Internet scripts to download from remote server to another server. All of the php scripts runs on my computer setup xampp but not on server.
I'm using Linux ubuntu php 7. 
Here's goes the following code which works fine on xampp but only out two lines on server and do nothing.

I changed the permission of folders and tried almost all general suggestion but nothing seems to work for me.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0); //Unlimited max execution time

$path = 'fille.jpg';
$url = 'https://www.pagalworld.live/GpE34Kg9Gq/113401/142856-main-deewana-tera-arjun-patiala-mp3-song-300.jpg';
$newfname = $path;
echo 'Starting Download!<br>';
$file = fopen ($url, "rb");
if($file) {
    $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");
    if($newf)
        while(!feof($file)) {
            fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
            echo '1 MB File Chunk Written!<br>';
        }
}
if($file) {
    fclose($file);
}
if($newf) {
    fclose($newf);
}
echo 'Finished!';


?>
```

Comment: And how does the "not works" manifest itself? In what way does the XAMPP differ from the Ubuntu install (php version, apache version,... )?

Comment: in xamp it download the remote file and saves to desired path while on server script dont do anything. Im running php 7 and latest version of apache as i recently updated while on xamp both things are outdated